# how to include multiple if statement conditions in jQuery

Tags: javascript, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I have an if statement that needs to look like this:
UPDATE

```
 $("input#textbox").keypress(function(e){
    key==e.which;
    if($("input#textbox").length <=7 && (key===13 || $("div#search-button").click())){
       /////SOME FUNCTION////
    };
 });
```

I'm trying to execute the "SOME FUNCTION" area only if the input length is <=7 and either the enter button is pressed or the "search" button is clicked.

Furthermore, I want to combine these 2 different function initiators so that they execute the same function but don't know how to do it:

```
  $("input#textbox").keypress(function(e){
     FUNCTION A
  };

  AND 

  $("div#search-button").click(function(){
     FUNCTION A
  };
```

Comment: What you're referring to is applicable to all of javascript. Adding parenthesis likely isn't your problem. You should paste the code that is breaking. Also, that semi-colon after your closing bracket could cause errors.

Comment: That's valid syntax, though I think you mean expression, not statement.  Not sure what the issue is.  More info may help.

Comment: @all - see the update in my OP

Comment: Unless jquery is doing something very odd, it seems like $("div#search-button").click() isn't going to return something that will tell you it was clicked...

Comment: @Tetsujin - true, so whats a remedy for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

This is what you have to do:

1. I am assuming that you want the text length and not number of textboxes.
2. You want to execute FunctionA when enter is pressed on textbox or search button is clicked:

```
     $("input#textbox").keypress(function(e){
        key==e.which;
        if (key === 13) // if enter is pressed
        {
           if ("#textbox").val().length >= 7) //if textbox has more than 7 characters
           {
               functionA();
           }
        }
     });
     $("div#search-button").click(function(){ functionA();});
```

HTH

Comment: @Raja - please see UPDATE in Original Post

Comment: Please check out the solution now. HTH

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
$("#search-button").click(function(){
    $("#textbox").keypress(function(e,clicked){
        (clicked || e.which===13) && $(this).val().length < 8 && functionA();
    }).trigger("keypress",[true]);
});
function functionA(){
    alert("hey!");
}
```